# Question about the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n+ 2^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, fake-proofs

I have one question about limits: it is required to find the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n + 2^n}$.

I calculated it like this:

$$(3^n+2^n)^{1/n} = \left(3^n \cdot \frac{3^n+2^n}{3^n}\right)^{1/n} \rightarrow (3^n)^{1/n} = 3.$$

but what if I divide, say by $5^n$:

$$\left(5^n \cdot \frac{3^n+2^n}{5^n}\right)^{1/n} \rightarrow (5^n \cdot 0)^{1/n} = 0.$$

Why is the second solution wrong?

Comment: The limit must not depend on $n$. You used the theorem "if $u_n\rightarrow\ell$ and $f$ is continuous then $f(u_n)\rightarrow f(\ell)$" but with $u_n=\frac{3^n+2^n}{3^n}$ (or $u_n=\frac{3^n+2^n}{5^n}$) and $f(x)=(3^nx)^{1/n}$ (or $f(x)=(5^nx)^{1/n}$) which depends on $n$ !

Comment: The case of $a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$ with $a\to0$ and $b\to0$ is an indeterminate case of the limit. That is what you get in $\left(\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n+\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$, since $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n+\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n\to0$ and $1/n\to0$. The point of multiplying and dividing by $3^n$ is that you get $\left(\frac{3}{3}\right)^n+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\to1$ and $1/n\to0$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien That is not a problem in the determinate cases of the arithmetic properties of the limit. If you know that you are not in an indeterminate case of one of the arithmetic properties of the limit, you can perfectly replace parts of an expression for their limits. That the notation becomes unusual doesn't mean that the operation cannot be justified. The real problem is that they did fall into an indetermined case.

Comment: @Boxwood Sorry, but I don't quite understand. Am I wrong in the calculations?

Comment: Yes, $((3/5)^n+(2/5)^n)^{1/n}$ doesn't tend to $0$. Your mistake is applying the result: If $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$, then $a_n^{b_n}\to a^b$ in a case in which this result doesn't  hold. Namely, the case where $a=b=0$. Note that when you divide and multiply by $3^n$ you end up in a case in which this result hold. Namely, the case $a=1$, $b=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$(3^n+2^n)^{1/n}=\left(5^n\cdot\frac{3^n+2^n}{5^n}\right)^{1/n}=5\cdot\left[\left(\frac35\right)^n+\left(\frac25\right)^n\right]^{1/n}.$$ Thus, when you concluded that the second limit is $0,$ you virtually assumed that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(\frac35\right)^n+\left(\frac25\right)^n\right]^{1/n}=0,$$ which is false. Your assumption is that since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac35\right)^n+\left(\frac25\right)^n=0,$$ that the former limit must also be $0.$ However, this is not the case: in the cases where the exponent has limit $0,$ it is not sufficient for the base to have limit $0$ in order for the entire power to have limit $0.$ The exponent is $1/n,$ and notice that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}=0.$$ As such, your second calculation is simply incorrect. In general, if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0,$$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{b_n}^{a_n}$$ can be equal to any nonnegative real number, or it can even not exist. You cannot simply conclude it to be $0.$

Comment: Ah, I see Boxwood has beat me to it and explained this in the comments while I was typing my answer.

Comment: I didn't beat you. It is not a competition.

Comment: @Boxwood I did not mean the phrase in that sense. "X beat me to it" is an idiom used in the English language when describing a situation in which a person covers something already covered. It is not an implication of competition.

Answer (score 1):

A separate approach:-

The expression just equals:-

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}3\left(1+(\frac{2}{3})^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$.

Now this is $1^{\infty}$ form.

You can use this whenever you run into this $1^{\infty}$ form

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp(\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-1)g(x))$$ when $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$ is $1^{\infty}$ form.

So using this we get it as :-

$$3\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{2}{3})^{n}}{n})=3\exp(0)=3$$.

In general whenever you have something like

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_{1}^{n}+a_{2}^{n}+...+a_{m}^{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$. where $a_{i}$'s are distinct positive real numbers.You can use the above method and immediately write the answer as :-  $\displaystyle\max_{1\leq i\leq m}a_{i}$.

That is we are strongly using the fact that $a^{n}\to 0$ when $0<a<1$.